# Unable to register rasphberry pi3 to cumulocity

Tags: cumulocity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFxmd.jpg)Unable to register raspberry pi3 to  website, I have installed agent and restarted and checked in site but no luck .
More details below 
I am running Raspberry Pi Desktop on raspberrypi . 
I have installed cumulocity agent by running following commands (full details followed as mentioned in https://cumulocity.com/guides/devices/raspberry-pi/ ).

$ wget http://resources.cumulocity.com/examples/cumulocity-rpi-agent-latest.deb
   $ sudo dpkg -i cumulocity-rpi-agent-latest.deb

I took serial number of device and have registered in https://agdemo.eu-latest.cumulocity.com and since them I see message waiting for connection

Software details
 Linux raspberrypi 4.14.79-v7+ #1159 SMP Sun Nov 4 17:50:20 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
 Raspberry Pi Desktop (https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/rpd_x86_latest) 
hardware details
Raphberry Pi Rc-A-752 3 Model B+
CPU info 
Hardware        : BCM2835
Revision        : a020d3
Serial          : 00000000a3fb6364
Memory info
1 GB RAM[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jbq2p.png)

[Screenshots]

[Cumulocity.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPhzF.png)
[agent status log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6GXB.png)

Comment: Hi there, could you add a little more information about what you're trying to accomplish here? Some more information on your hardware, operating system, language you're using and tools and so-on and hopefully someone will be able to help.

For more information on how to ask a good stack overflow question check:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap credentials are not your personal credentials.

You can follow the instructions in the documentation: https://cumulocity.com/guides/device-sdk/rest#step-0-request-device-credentials

Taken from there:

> The device will connect to Cumulocity and send its unique ID repeatedly. For this purpose, Cumulocity provides static credentials that can be enquired by contacting support.

These are the bootstrap credentials that you need.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set the bootstrap credentials. The default credentials are included in the agent implementation. Setting the host property only is sufficient in the .properties file. To retry also delete the device.properties file if existing. This file is generated by the agent after successful registration.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am not allowed to add a comment.
Could you run the agent using java giving debug log config to get verbose info and post the log.

```
$ cd /usr/share/cumulocity-rpi-agent
$ java -cp 'cfg/*:lib/*' -Dlogback.configurationFile=cfg/logback-debug.xml c8y.lx.agent.Agent
```

Comment: Default credentials just works fine except that they are only valid to host management.cumulocity.com and the log shows that no new device registration found.
Apr  4 10:11:40 raspberrypi root: 10:11:40.663 [pool-3-thread-1] INFO  c.c.s.c.p.AlteringRateResultPoller - Polling with wrong result: Http status code: 404
Apr  4 10:11:40 raspberrypi root: {error="devicecontrol/Not Found",message="There is no newDeviceRequest for device id 00000000a3fb6364.",info="https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/reference-guide/#error_reporting",
Apr  4 10:11:40 raspberrypi root: 10:11:40.664 [pool-3-thr

Comment: I was able to connect to my cumulocity instance with the default credentials. However, it is a custom instance `https://<company_name>.iot.telstra.com`. Could you replace host entry in `/usr/share/cumulocity-rpi-agent/cfg/cumulocity.properties` with `host = https://agdemo.eu-latest.cumulocity.com`, then run the agent as a java program and send the full log.